# How to achieve customization for dealer functionality or extension

Tags: magento2, b2b

Im trying to look the extension or solution for a B2B solution.

1. Marketing executive(admin role) account  creates dealer account(customer) and manager approves(admin role)
2. After approval of dealer, account send mail to different parties saying the new dealer is created and approved
3. Marketing executive place a quote for the dealer and manager should approve
4. After approval sends mail to different parties

Comment: I don't think there will be any extension with the exact requirement. You need to customise or create a new module to achieve the requirements.

Comment: do you any suggestion for the closest fit so we can customize it?

Comment: That's not fair to vote negative on these types of questions. I mean every one has rights to ask question here related to Magento. I don't think this question is wrong. +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not get exactly same module that will fulfill your requirements, but you can customize magento functionality and add some relevant modules that are close to your requirements

1. https://marketplace.magento.com/iwd-b2b.html
   This is a B2B module that will give you some restrictions and more features on login/signup pages
2. https://marketplace.magento.com/cart2quote-module-propoza.html
   This one is for quotation. It converts cart into quotation and this quotation sent to a portal where you can check and approve quotation. You can also give some discount on that quotation and that discount would be used at the time of checkout.

You can find many more like these on magento marketplace.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your thoughts, considering your inputs i found few other extensions but you pointed me to right direction. These are few extension iam evaluating just like you shared,https://amasty.com/sales-reps-and-dealers.html  and https://www.cart2quote.com/